# For Loop in cmd and powershell - 1 is unexpected at this time

Tags: powershell, scripting, batch

I need to run a `for` loop, from powershell, in cmd... aka, at the PS Prompt:

```
cmd /c For /L %i in (1,1,5) DO (Echo %i)
```

But, I get a "1 is unexpected at this time"

Other responses in my research indicate "`%i`" is command line, and "`%%i`" is script/batch -- but I've tried both and neither worked.  Any ideas?  Is it not possible?

Comment: `cmd /c 'For /L %i in (1,1,5) DO (Echo %i)'`

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  I encountered another problem later and was working with single quotes to resolve it -- don't know why i didn't think of it here.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: Why would you want to do a `cmd` script from PowerShell?  Instead do it in PowerShell:  `1..5 |% { Write-Host $_ }`

Answer (score 0):

By the [*About Quoting Rules*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) help topic (`Get-Help about_quoting_rules -Full`), use single or double quotes as follows:

```
. cmd /c 'For /L %i in (2,2,5) DO @(Echo %i)'
```

> ```
> 2
> 4
> ```

or

```
$step=2
. cmd /c "For /L %i in (2,$step,5) DO @(Echo %i)"
```

> ```
> 2
> 4
> ```

However, by the [*About Parsing*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) help topic (`Get-Help about_parsing -Full`), there are more ways to achieve this:

- by *ad hoc* escaping some PowerShell-poisonous symbols e.g. `()` *parentheses*, `$` *Dollar Sign*, `@` *Commercial At* etc., see also `Get-Help about_Escape_Characters` <sub>(online version not found)</sub>. In Windows PowerShell, the escape character is the `` ` `` *backtick*, also called the *grave accent* (codepoint `U+0060`, ASCII `96`).:

```
cmd /c For /L %i in `(2,1,4`) DO `@`(Echo %i`)
```

> ```
> 2
> 3
> 4
> ```

- by using the ***stop-parsing symbol*** (`--%`)` (**introduced in PowerShell 3.0**, directs PowerShell to refrain from interpreting input as PowerShell commands or expressions).  This technique is much easier than using escape characters to prevent misinterpretation:

```
cmd /c --% For /L %i in (2,1,4) DO @(Echo %i)
```

> ```
> 2
> 3
> 4
> ```